# Basic idea of zero inflated two part models(hurdel) and application to big data (machine learning)

Tags: machine-learning, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution, zero-inflation

I'm currently working on the data which has 90% 0s in response variable. Based on my research, it seems zero inflated models could be a solution to this. However, while I was reading related documents, it seems the basic idea of two part model( hurdel) is

$    E[Y|X] = P(Y>0|X)  E[Y|X,Y>0]$

The question is will it be okay if I use any model to get both `P(Y>0|X)` and `E[Y|X,Y>0]` ,and multiply the result of those two?
More specifically, in R code would be like

```
#for first model
FirstModel=randomforest(Y,X) #random forest 
First_pred=predict(FristModel,newdata,type='prob')

#for second model
SecondModel=glmnet(Y~X) #glm with L1 L2 penalty
Second_pred=predict(SecondModel,newdata)


#for E[Y|X] = P(Y>0|X) * E[Y|X,Y>0]
First_pred * Second_pred
```

Will this make sense in view of machine learning modeling strategy? In other wards, will this improve accuracy of prediction without considering interpretation?